# How to ignore index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I found that one of the indexes is slowing my Query...but I can't drop it because it is used else where and it seems it is a good index for that query.

Is there a way in SQL Server 2005+, where I could ignore an index in a Query?

Comment: Can you show proof that an index is actually slowing down your query? How about posting the query, the table structure (including indexes) and the actual execution plan?

Comment: I too wonder how an index could slow a query. Is your evidence that you dropped it and your query was faster? If so, SQL recompiled any query plans that involved the table, so it could have been that.